# Is it possible to access the customized SignUp page (of the combined SignInUp policy) directly?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When using the combined SignIn/Up policy in Azure AD B2C, the user normally gets the (optionally customized) SignIn Page with the extra link to register for a new account.

But is there a possibility to access the SignUp page directly, without having to go via the SignIn page?
Is there any special query string parameter to control the behavior of the page display, i.e. whether to show the SignIn or SignUp part?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sign-up policy, as described at [Azure Active Directory B2C: Built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-policy), for this specific journey.

As long as you configure the same settings (application claims, identity providers, token settings, etc.) for the sign-up policy as that for the sign-up or sign-in policy, then you should realize the same result.